# Splitting PPT animation using C#

Tags: c#, macros, powerpoint

This is the last resort of my problem.
I'm trying to split animated PPT slides into several flattened slides.

1. http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2007/11/powerpoint-pdf-part-2.html
   I have translated the code into C#, and it works fine, except it doesn't handle appearing/disappearing bullets.
2. http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/~rimondin/downloads/PPspliT/1.1/PPspliT-source.txt
   This works better when being run as an add-in or a macro.
   The problem is that it's hard (read: too long) to translate it into C#.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to detect/split the bullets by just using the code from link #1?
   This is the preferable method since the code is already simple.
2. If that's not possible, can I create/run the macro from C# in the runtime? The macro would have not been installed/existed in the PPT file.
   I imagine this will be impossible since macro feature would have to be enabled in the PowerPoint program before it could be run.
3. Other solutions are welcomed!

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433059/writing-custom-code-for-powerpoint#

Have a look,any idea about this??